# How to force only shutdown after accidentally pressing restart?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

We've all been there.

You're shutting down your computer after a long day of work, so you press Start, the power button, then go to click <kbd>Shutdown</kbd>... only to move your mouse just a bit too much or too little, and accidentally click on that damned restart button. Now we have to wait until the computer reaches the login screen, so that we can shut it down again.

While it doesn't seem to be much of a problem, on older systems with slow HDDs, this sequence can take several minutes, which is quite annoying.

**After pressing restart, is there a way to force the computer to *only* shutdown?** Alternatively, when is the safest time to press the power button in order to manually shutdown the computer before it restarts?

Comment: Safest would be to not make the error in the first place. WinKey+X then U then U will shutdown, no clicking required. [For sake of completeness Win/X, U, R will restart]

Comment: The safest moment to turn the power button is when you see the bios screen. But with windows 10 and fast boot, that is a split second moment, so waiting is probably better, and don't make mistakes. If you really can't afford it, either use windows key combinations or create a shortcut and click that. `shutdown -s -t 0`  is the command to execute a shutdown.